# SQL Server, how to find the operation performed at particular @@dbts

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know that `@@dbts` time stamp get incremented for each insert , update or delete

Now suppose `Select @@dbts` gives me 2505.

How can I know which operation (insert/update/delete) is performed when `@@dbts` is 2504 which caused it to become 2505

Comment: I don't believe that there's anything built in to support this - I think you'd have to apply triggers to every `rowversion` containing table. Perhaps if we knew how you planned to use this info, we could suggest an alternative?

Comment: I'm not convinced that all `@@dbts` values get used either. [When answering this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11085/sql-server-management-studio-2008-sucks-up-with-memory-yielding-net-runtime-fai/11088#11088) I found that inserting 1 million rows seemed to increment it by `1003921` rather than 1 million so not sure if some are used for internal purposes or some just get skipped.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're monitoring every query call within the system and every one has an output value for the @@DBTS, there's no way to know this.